# Is bedding-in the brakes really necessary for regular street cars?

Tags: brakes, break-in

So I'm reading stuff about bedding-in the brakes. I'm reading the [Centric](https://www.apcautotech.com/getmedia/b62c7705-ab5f-4a05-97a8-4a7390feedd1/Centric_and_APC_Technical_Whitepaper_C2-Bed-In-Theory-8-2018_1.pdf) [Whitepapers](https://www.apcautotech.com/getmedia/231712d7-a4d8-4e06-ace6-a766f704a664/Centric_and_APC_Technical_Whitepaper_C5-Bed-In-FAQ-8-2018.pdf). And by "regular street cars" I mean the "normal" cars your [normal] mom or your [normal] dad use.

I've just replaced rotors, pads and brake fluid (service done by a mechanic, not me) of my [regular street] car. And here is exactly where the problem lies: the aforementioned whitepapers are geared towards performance or even *racing* cars. I'll quote:

[Bedding-in definition](https://www.apcautotech.com/getmedia/b62c7705-ab5f-4a05-97a8-4a7390feedd1/Centric_and_APC_Technical_Whitepaper_C2-Bed-In-Theory-8-2018_1.pdf):

> bed-in is the process of depositing an even layer of brake pad
>   material, or transfer layer, on the rubbing surface of the rotor disc.

[Un-bedding the brakes](https://www.apcautotech.com/getmedia/231712d7-a4d8-4e06-ace6-a766f704a664/Centric_and_APC_Technical_Whitepaper_C5-Bed-In-FAQ-8-2018.pdf):

> If any brake pad is used below its adherent operating temperature, it
>   will create friction through primarily abrasive mechanisms, slowly but
>   surely removing the transfer layer on the rotor.
>
> If the brakes are used passively for an extended period of time, the
>   transfer layer can be completely removed, effectively un-bedding the
>   brakes.

And to make matters worse, I almost never hit my brakes very hard (unless for emergency) so I'm almost a perfect fit to the second quote above (in case you're wondering, yes, I use engine braking a lot). In that case, then I see no reason for bedding-in my brakes because I'll be *un-bedding* them for 99% of the time!

Comment: SolarMike's answer basically covers this - but just to add in that the key thing in the un-bedding seciont is *"below its adherent operating temperature"* barring specialist pads road brakes have an operating temp range that pretty much encompasses using them when "cold" so it's not really applicable.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just installed a new set of Akebono ceramic pads on my car, and they say that no bedding is needed.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - I have no doubt the brakes state that, but I'll continue to bed my brakes no matter the manufacturer of the friction material and what they say. That's JMHO, though, so take it for what it's worth :o)

Comment: @motosubatsu The article starts with "_If **any brake pad** is used below its adherent operating temperature_", so in my understanding the un-bedding issues _should apply_ to the brakes of regular street cars as well, that's why I'm asking. Not sure if I understood what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

The good and reputable mechanic will normally take the car for a road test (or tested by a separate person - foreman or road-tester etc) before you get it back - which will have "bedded in" the brakes.

All you need to worry about is driving it - the performance of the brakes is ample in day to day situations and you will not be using the brakes under race conditions.

Comment: While I agree with you *the mechanic **should*** bed the brakes, doesn't mean they will. Some places are just there to get the customer out the door. On a separate note, I'm not quite sure this really answers the question at large, especially if taken from the perspective of the average home DIYer doing their own brake replacement. Are you saying if you are the one who is replacing the brakes (ie: *you* are the mechanic), you *should* then bed your brakes? Can you give any differentiation between what the OP is stating and why? Links to references?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Indeed my question still remains: _is it really necessary to bed-in the brakes of a regular street car?_ Regardless, I will [try to] execute the procedure and I already have a place (an expressway) and time (early hours of sunday) in mind. I will use the [C3 Whitepaper](https://www.apcautotech.com/getmedia/6cf1f374-ec63-433c-84ad-08cc596acc42/Centric_and_APC_Technical_Whitepaper_C3-Bed-In-Stock-8-2018_1.pdf) procedure (but less aggressively, from 45~50mph to 15~20mph, instead of 60 to 10mph).